# Running HDFS commands on a dataproc cluster if you can't SSH onto the master node

Tags: hdfs, google-cloud-dataproc

Is there a way of submitting HDFS commands on a Dataproc cluster, if you can't SSH into the master node. I couldn't find anything in the Gcloud SDK or the rest API.

So something like :

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit hdfs 'ls /hdfs/path/' --cluster=my-cluster --region=europe-west1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is [pig fs](https://pig.apache.org/docs/latest/cmds.html#fs) via `gcloud dataproc jobs submit pig --execute 'fs -ls /'`, or otherwise `pig sh` as a catch-all for other shell commands.

Comment: just stumbled on this (can't remember where I came from). Very cool, thx Dennis.